# windbg and symbols

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windbg, symbols

When I set a breakpoint on one of the methods that appears on top of the stack (!CLRStack), I get lots of these messages for every DLL that the debuggee is referencing including the .NET Framework ones.

**ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded**

Further digging into this shows that windbg is not loading every .pdb file that I make available in the symbols path. I've double-checked my symbol's path and it looks OK, but the following commands clearly show that not all PDBs are loaded correctly!

> 0:000> !sym noisy
>   noisy mode - symbol prompts on
>   0:000> .reload
>   Reloading current modules
>   ................................................................
>   DBGHELP: ntdll - public symbols
>            c:\symbols\ntdll.pdb\6992F4DAF4B144068D78669D6CB5D2072\ntdll.pdb
>   ..
>   0:000> .sympath
>   Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\symbols*C:\xc
>   Expanded Symbol search path is: srv*c:\symbols*c:\xc

I've c:\symbols being used for the cache and c:\xc being used for the .NET app PDBs that WinDBG seems unable to find. Any idea how I can use to help further troubleshoot this?

Thanks

Comment: Try doing `.reload /f` to force already-loaded modules to be reloaded with new symbols.

Answer (score 1):

The *SRV* prefix implies the directory is laid out like a symbol server. If you have a directory that does not use the symbol server hiarchy, you should just use `C:\Symbols;C:xc` instead of `SRV*C:\Symbols*C:\Xc`

Comment: Thanks. I missed this response :-)